# If I forfeited my entire dependent care FSA, can I claim dependent care credit?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dependents, dcfsa

I missed the deadline to claim my dependent care FSA for a previous year. 
Since the entire FSA amount was forfeited, can I claim dependent care credit instead for that year ?

Answer (score 3):

No.  You already received the deduction, since that lost FSA money was pre-tax.  You can't double dip.  However if your FSA amount was less than your actual expenses, you can file on the difference.

Example: $4500 actual expenses, $3000 FSA (lost).  You can get the dependent care credit based on $1500.